# Create multiple connections to a websocket in tokio-tungstenite using multiple local IPs

Tags: rust, websocket, rust-tokio

I'm retrieving all the local IP addresses and I want to create websocket connections from each of these IPs.

How do I cycle through all `ips` and create multiple `stream`s?

```
use std::net::{IpAddr, Ipv4Addr};
use tokio_tungstenite::connect_async;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    let ips: Vec<IpAddr> = vec![
        IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(1, 1, 1, 1)),
        IpAddr::V4(Ipv4Addr::new(2, 2, 2, 2))
    ];

    // How do I cycle through all `ips` and create multiple `stream`s?
    let (mut stream, _) = connect_async("wss://echo.websocket.org").await.unwrap();

    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            Some(msg) = stream.next() => {
                println!("{}", msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to move the comment from the code block into the body of the question.

Comment: Are you looking for a `for` loop⁉

Comment: No. I want to map each local IP address to a stream.

Comment: It seems like you want a `Vec<WebSocketStream<...>>`, if so just use a for loop. Convert `IpAddr` to a `Uri`

Comment: @user2407038, the `wss://localhost:433` may not have been the best `Uri` but this should be external, not local. I've provided a different `Uri` I connect to. I want to have `n` external streams bound to `n` local IPs.

Comment: And what is the problem with something as simple as [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b3d1a5c1e4af187c820b5e0abaf2cf9b)?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: I think your proposal changes the target IP, that is it will connect to `1.1.1.1` instead of `echo.websocket.org`. But it looks to me that the OP wants to connect to that server from the local IP `1.1.1.1` instead from the default `any` IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to determine your local address you have to manually create the `TcpStream` and switch to `client_async` instead of `connect_async`:

```
use futures::{stream::SelectAll, StreamExt};
use std::net::{Ipv4Addr, SocketAddr, SocketAddrV4};
use tokio::net::{lookup_host, TcpSocket};
use tokio_tungstenite::client_async;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // we set the ports here to 0 so the OS can pick one for us
    let ips: Vec<SocketAddr> = vec![
        SocketAddr::V4(SocketAddrV4::new(Ipv4Addr::new(1, 1, 1, 1), 0)),
        SocketAddr::V4(SocketAddrV4::new(Ipv4Addr::new(2, 2, 2, 2), 0)),
    ];
    let mut streams = SelectAll::new();
    // get the first remote address you might want to try them one after the other or maybe `zip` them with the ones from `ips`, …
    let target = lookup_host("echo.websocket.org:443")
        .await?
        .next()
        .ok_or("no IP for \"echo.websocket.org:443\"")?;
    for ip in ips {
        let socket = TcpSocket::new_v4()?;
        socket.bind(ip)?;
        let tcp_stream = socket.connect(target).await?;

        let (ws_stream, _) = client_async("wss://echo.websocket.org", tcp_stream)
            .await?;
        streams.push(ws_stream);
    }

    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            Some(msg) = streams.next() => {
                println!("{:?}", msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using `SelectAll` to join all the streams into one here, you might want to replace it with a `Vec` to have easy access to all the different streams individually. Or you could use [`SelectAll::iter(_mut)`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/select_all/struct.SelectAll.html#method.iter_mut)